# Identify Novel about Russia/United States where Boris Yeltsin downed pills with vodka and died

Tags: story-identification, novel, history

I'm trying to remember the title of a book I was reading for a short time while working an unpleasant job last year haha.

I thought Tom Clancy was the author, but I looked up his novels & none of the titles looked familiar. So it took place in 1999 I'm fairly certain, Boris Yeltsin downed pills with vodka & died early into the novel. Yeltsin's successor (not Putin in the book) went to the White House to seek economic aid for Russia (budgets & Congress were mentioned)—at the same time there was some kind of secret operation going on with the CIA against Russia with aiding Russian operatives I think, and Yeltsin's successor had a counter-op against the U.S. in the background too.

Sorry if I'm a bit sketchy on the details, I'm really trying to remember because I actually liked it. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I've flagged the question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy (or, for that matter, anything within the broader scope of speculative fiction). If, in fact, there are science fiction or fantasy elements in the story at all, it would behove you to edit the question and make it clear how the question is relevant to this site.

Comment: You can just delete it then, no problem.

Comment: Would Boris Yeltsin dying in 1999 qualify it as alternate history?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about scifi or fantasy

Comment: Sorry dude, sounds interesting, but unfortunately not sci-fi related. If you can remember _any_ sci-fi or post-apocalyptic elements, it would make it on-topic though!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Boris Yeltsin did not die in 1999, thus making this pretty clearly an alternate history question. And alternate history, according to [this ancient post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/44/82909) is **on topic**.

Comment: @Laurel When asked to clarify the relevance of their post, the Questioner did not choose to expand upon it or edit their question to highlight that they are really after a work which is at least spec-fi, if not pure scifi/fantasy. They instead suggested to delete it, which implies they agree with the assessment of off-topicness. Furthermore, the work you identified in your answer was written in 1997, two years before the setting of the book; while that makes it a conjecture about the future, it was neither alt-history nor did it contain scientific or fantastic elements.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like [Politika (Tom Clancy's Power Plays, Book 1)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0425162788). On the first page, Boris Yeltsin is popping aspirins with Vodka and wondering if that might kill him.

> It is 1999. The sudden death of Russia's president has thrown the Russian Federation into chaos. Devastating crop failures have left millions in the grip of famine, and an uprising seems inevitable.
>
> One of Russia's provisional leaders asks the American president for help. But the whole world is watching when a deadly terrorist attack stuns the United States and evidence points to the Russian government.